# Removing the second line of an address when it is null in an Access 2007 report?

Tags: microsoft-access, label, report

I'm trying to use the [CanShrink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb239954%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property in a report in Access 2007 so that if the mailingAddress2 field from my query is null or blank it will collapse the Address 2 field and move the mailingCity, mailingState fields up.

All the fields shown are text boxes.

[image: Mailing Address Labels with the field I want to shrink]

I read about the [CanShrink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb239954%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property and I don't know what else I need to try collapse the field.

Comment: There's something here (http://en.allexperts.com/q/Using-MS-Access-1440/2008/1/Shrink-work.htm) that says you have to set the "CanShrink property for the text box AND the section it's in to YES" what's the section detail?

Comment: Concatenating a space may prevent the field from shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your data source (query) to add a new field or just add a text box and apply to the control source property.

Query Field:  MailingAddres1and2: IIf(IsNull(MailingAddress1), MailingAddress, MailingAddress & Chr(10) & MailingAddress)

or Control Source of a Text box:  =IIf(IsNull(MailingAddress1), MailingAddress, MailingAddress & Chr(10) & MailingAddress)

Chr(10) will insert a carriage return.